# Run R web scrape daily

Tags: r, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a script written in R that pulls online and then exports it to a spreadsheet on my computer. I am attempting to create a batch file so that I can set up a scheduled task, but it only opens up the R file without actually running it. The batch file is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe" CMD BATCH 
"C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\xxx\Scraper.r"
```

I am very open to ideas other than creating a batch file, I just want this to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this instead (note the x64 addition)

```
 "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\xxx\Scraper.r
```

and without the CMD BATCH flags. That works for me.

I am not sure what is going on, but it may be you only have the 64 bit version installed, and you are trying to execute the 32 bit version. But I get a silent fail when I don't have specify the "x64" sub-directory.